# Why is my disconnect() handler not getting fired in SignalR Client Side JS?

Tags: signalr, signalr-hub, signalr.client

I'm seeing some odd/unexpected behaviour using the SignalR 2.0.3 libraries.

I'm trying to hook some call backs in the client and they don't seem to be getting fired.
I'd really like to get the reconnecting, reconnected and disconnected call backs working in JS - client side.
SignalR does connect successfully and I've got communication between the server and client.

**Here are a couple of code snippets:**

```
$.connection.reconnecting = function () {
    alert("reconnecting");
};
$.connection.reconnected = function () {
    alert("We have been reconnected");
};
$.connection.disconnected = function () {
    alert("We are disconnected!");
};
```

I could have sworn that I had these firing when I was using SignalR 1.x.
Currently, we using version 2.0.3.

I'm running a 2 machine setup where my server app (and hub) is on 1 machine.

**Here are the steps I'm using to reproduce:**

1)  Connect from a second machine. I looked at the network traffic in the browser
      console and it looks ok.

2) Next I disconnect the client machine from the network. In the console I see SignalR
     attempting to reconnect. (This is as expected)

3) Ultimately after N retries, it looks like it disconnects. (I see the final retry is "Canceled"
     in the console output.

4) However, my disconnected() handler does not get called.

Any insights or thoughts how to track this down?

Thanks,
JohnB

Answer (score 3):

With SignalR 2.x, you can register your callbacks like this:

```
$.connection.hub.reconnecting(function() {
    alert("reconnecting"); 
});

$.connection.hub.reconnected(function() {
    alert("We have been reconnected"); 
});

$.connection.hub.disconnected(function() {
    alert("We are disconnected!"); 
});
```

You can also add callbacks using `$.connection.hub.stateChanged()`. See [documentation](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/signalr-20/hubs-api/hubs-api-guide-javascript-client#connectionlifetime).

Comment: I'm still not seeing these firing as I would expect. I'm using SignalR 2.0.3. I'm running in Windows 7 with IIS 7. It seems that the protocol being used is "ServerSentMessages." Can anyone help me figure out the root cause of this issue? Thanks, JB

Comment: I was having the same issue as JohnB, and registering my disconnected handler rather than directly on the hub proxy object solved the problem.